# Pine script code to make long position via strategy.entry function

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to make some strategies for just a trial.

But I can't understand the timing of getting the open and close price.
(and also executing timing of strategy.entry works)

Let's assume that I want to make an order when the current price is crossover middle price of BB.

So, I wrote code like this

```
[middle, upper, lower] = ta.bb(close, 20, 2)
plot(middle, color=color.yellow)
plot(upper, color=color.blue)
plot(lower, color=color.blue)
lc = ta.crossover(close,middle)
if lc
    strategy.entry("L", strategy.long,limit = open)
```

With this code, I expected that if current bar's close price is over middle of BB
make a long position on the next bar's open price.

But It wasn't made at the time I thought.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znvJY.png)

As you can see, Long position was made after the bar I thought
(Red arrow is the timing which I expected to make long position)

and also, I expected to make long position with open price but It was not made on open price of bar.

My intention was to make long entry in the open price of the bar corresponding to the red arrow.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `limit` in your `strategy.entry()` function, it will place a limit order.

You want to enter with a market order so you just need to call the `strategy.entry()` whenever your condition is `true`.

```
lc = ta.crossover(close, middle)
if lc
    strategy.entry("L", strategy.long)
```

Comment: What if I try to order specific price like open price? As I konw, If I wanna do that, I have to use limit order. Does limit order could be failed cuz tradingview reflects real situation at that time and could be igonred my order?

Answer (score 0):

in the strategy.entry() function, the limit parameter should be set to limit = close.  this will open a trade at the level of the close of the bar that satisfies input conditions.  the trade will open on the next bar.

strategy.order("Long", true, *when = buy03*, **limit = close**)